# How can I apply hierarchical clustering on a sparse correlation matrix in R (NaN dissimilarity value)?

Tags: cluster-computing, sparse-matrix

I have been searching similar questions and attempting to adapt the proposed solutions to my question below but to no avail. I am fairly new in using R, I must add. I have a microbiome OTU table 125 samples 96 taxa, wish to obtain taxa co-abundance groups; when I eliminate r<0.2 (and p<0.05) values from the taxa corr. matrix (96x96) the resulting sparse matrix, after converting it to a distance matrix (gower or manhattan), cannot be clustered due to NAs. The hclust function generates "NaN dissimilarity value". Here is a subset of 96x96 cor. matrix:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErbzW.png)

I have tried dist,vegdist,daisy functions in converting corr. matrix to a distance matrix (na.rm=T, if applicable), and hclust or agnes functions to obtain a hierarchical clustering dendogram.

Thank you!